# Cauchy's formula on function at the pole not inside

Tags: analysis

How can one define the integral when the pole is on the integration contour?

$$\int_{|w|=1}\dfrac{1}{i-w}\, dw$$

Comment: Did you mean $w$ instead of $\theta$?

Answer (score 2):

The integral of interest $I=\oint_{|w|=1}\frac{1}{i-w}\,dw$ does not exist since the pole of the integrand intersects the integration contour.

---

However, the Cauchy Principal value of the integral does exist and is given by

$$\begin{align}
\text{PV}\left(\oint_{|w|=1}\frac{1}{i-w}\,dw \right)&\equiv \lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+}\int_\pi^{2\pi}\frac{i\varepsilon e^{i\theta}}{i-(i+\varepsilon e^{i\theta})}\,d\theta\\\\
&=-i\pi
\end{align}$$

We defined the Cauchy Principal Value to be the limit of integration over a deformed unit circle as the arc length of the deformation approaches $0$.  Here, the deformation is an "infinitesimal semi-circular dent" at $w=i$, parameterized by $w_{\text{dent}}=i+\varepsilon e^{i\theta}$, $\pi\le \theta\le 2\pi$.

---

Alternatively and equivalently, we can define the Cauchy Principal Values as the limit of the simple arithmetic average of the integrals over circular contours of raddii $1+\varepsilon$ and $1-\varepsilon$ as $\varepsilon\to 0$.  Proceeding, we find that

$$\begin{align}
\text{PV}\left(\oint_{|w|=1}\frac{1}{i-w}\,dw \right)&\equiv \frac12\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+}\left(\underbrace{\oint_{|w|=1+\varepsilon}\frac{1}{i-w}\,dw}_{=-2\pi i}+\underbrace{\oint_{|w|=1-\varepsilon}\frac{1}{i-w}\,dw}_{=0}\right)\\\\
&=-i\pi
\end{align}$$

as expected!

Comment: @ AbdelhamidRehouma Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can.